# определение длины len и добавление в round

Tags: python

Как задать в len() так что он посчитал все значения после точки
К примеру есть:

```
a = '0.005'
```

мы хотим получить длину после точки. Значит после точки длина 3 (005)

и узнав длину после точки в переменной a мы хотим из переменной b:

```
b = 0.011111
```

сказать что бы переменную b после точки округлило до значений (3) которую мы узнали в переменной a используя len

в итоге round должен округлить в переменной b плавающие точки до значения 3 и выдать результат:

```
b = 0.011
```

пытался так:

```
a1 = len(a)
b1 = round(b, a1)
```

но в этом случае a1 считает 4 значение и с самой точкой а мы хотели посчитать все значения которые после точки и вставить его в round

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения.

Comment: добавил изменения и пояснения

Answer (score 1):

1 вариант:

```
a = '0.005'
b = 0.011111
a_reversed = a[::-1]  # перевернутая строка a
dot_position = a_reversed.find('.')  # находим индекс . в строке a_reversed
b1 = round(b, dot_position)
```

Можно сократить до:

```
b1 = round(b, a[::-1].find('.'))
```

2 вариант:

```
a = '0.005'
b = 0.011111
a.split('.') # разбиваем строку a по . и получаем список ['0', '005']
dot_position = len(a.split('.')[1]) # получаем длину второго элемента списка '005'
b1 = round(b, dot_position)
```

Сокращаем:

```
b1 = round(b, len(a.split('.')[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Из не предложенных в других ответах вариантов есть ещё такой:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1HBVkHdQM/AwFSdKwnIBjINQQDMKcovzUvRSNJRyEnN00jUVNBVSNQrSssEiqnrqYO4hppcBUWZeSUaSZr//wMA)

```py
a = '0.005'
b = 0.011111
b = round(b, len(a) - a.rfind('.') - 1)
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
0.011
```

Answer (score 0):

Все у вас хорошо, только вместо **первой** строки вашего

```
a1 = len(a)
b1 = round(b, a1)
```

примените

```
__, after = a.split(".")
а1 = len(after)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

`a.split(".")` сделает из строки `a` список из 2 строк: части *перед* точкой и части *после* точки.

Из этого списка мы можем выбрать индивидуальные элементы распакованием

```
before, after = ....
```

но т.к. `before` (часть перед точкой) *нас вообще не интересует*, в соответствии с хорошим стилем мы для него применим специальное имя `__` (один или 2 знака подчеркивания):

```
__, after = a.split(".")
```